# Run jar file from batch file and if some error occurs show meessage

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a jar file, which is opening two files and in the first one is replacing content and in the second one is removing content. So i want to start this jar file through batch-file but i want when it starts to shows a message that is successfully started and if it is not to print error message that it is not and call "force(-f)" command. I know there must be some check but i do not know how. Could you help me with the script ? Here is my script code for now :

```
@ECHO OFF
start java -jar jarFile.jar
echo Successfully started!
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that :

```
@ECHO OFF
IF not exist jarFile.jar GOTO ERROR1
if exist jarFile.jar Start java -jar jarFile.jar
ECHO Successfully started!
PAUSE
EXIT
:ERROR1
ECHO File not found
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: yes it is fine, but i want to check when some error like the bat file doesnt start from specific directory or some exception occurs in jar file to  show  error message. Maybe it have to be with ErrorLevels, but do not know how

Comment: What does the `ERRORLEVEL` relate to in this case? If `Start` couldn't find a command or executable named `java` would `ERRORLEVEL` be `1`;  if `java` couldn't find `jarFile.jar` would `ERRORLEVEL` be `1`; should an error occur during the running of `jarFile.jar` through `java` under `Start` would the `ERRORLEVEL` be `1`.

Comment: In this case when i try to run jar file that does not exist, it doesn`t show me the error or it is at another place

Comment: you can have a look at this page : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrsnrub/2010/06/06/batch-files-basic-error-checking-and-running-as-scheduled-tasks/

Comment: Can a ask you one more question. If any problem occurs in the jar file is it possible to be handle in the script and show message for that ?

Comment: if any problem happens in jar file then your computer should display an error popup like corrupt file or something else.  but if it is internal problem of jar file that does not display the error but not work as desired i am in doubt if it would be possible to handle that

Comment: Yeah maybe it can be handled somehow i will search for it in the code of jar file, whatever thanks again .